# No property u found for type com.models.entities.OrderEntity

Tags: java, spring, log4j

I'm receiving the error `No property u found for type com.models.entities.OrderEntity` and for the life of me can't figure out how to debug where this is coming from.  I'm guessing there's some mapping that is incorrect.

I've tried enabling `log4j` which only gives me details on `org.hibernate`.  I tried adding other packages but they aren't being read.  I believe my `log4j.properties` is in the right location.

[image]

`log4j.properties` contents:

```
log4j.rootCategory=DEBUG, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %t %c:%L - %m%n

log4j.category.org.springframework.data=DEBUG,stdout
log4j.category.com.models.entities =DEBUG,stdout
```

What can I do to ensure log4j is logging the correct packages?

My entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "`Order`")
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name="Order.findByUUID", query="SELECT o FROM OrderEntity o WHERE o.uuid = :uuid"),
        @NamedQuery(name="Order.findByInProduction", query="SELECT o FROM OrderEntity o WHERE o.inProduction = :inProduction")
})
public class OrderEntity {
    private Integer id;

    @javax.persistence.Column(name = "id", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 10, precision = 0)
    @GeneratedValue
    @Id
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    private String uuid;

    @javax.persistence.Column(name = "uuid", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 128, precision = 0)
    @Basic
    public String getUuid() {
        return uuid;
    }

    public void setUuid(String uuid) {
        this.uuid = uuid;
    }

    private Boolean inProduction;

    @javax.persistence.Column(name = "in_production", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 0, precision = 0)
    @Basic
    public Boolean getInProduction() {
        return inProduction;
    }

    public void setInProduction(Boolean inProduction) {
        this.inProduction = inProduction;
    }

    private Timestamp updated;

    @javax.persistence.Column(name = "updated", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 19, precision = 0)
    @Basic
    public Timestamp getUpdated() {
        return updated;
    }

    public void setUpdated(Timestamp updated) {
        this.updated = updated;
    }

    private Timestamp created;

    @javax.persistence.Column(name = "created", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 19, precision = 0)
    @Basic
    public Timestamp getCreated() {
        return created;
    }

    public void setCreated(Timestamp created) {
        this.created = created;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        OrderEntity that = (OrderEntity) o;

        if (created != null ? !created.equals(that.created) : that.created != null) return false;
        if (id != null ? !id.equals(that.id) : that.id != null) return false;
        if (inProduction != null ? !inProduction.equals(that.inProduction) : that.inProduction != null) return false;
        if (updated != null ? !updated.equals(that.updated) : that.updated != null) return false;
        if (uuid != null ? !uuid.equals(that.uuid) : that.uuid != null) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0;
        result = 31 * result + (uuid != null ? uuid.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (inProduction != null ? inProduction.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (updated != null ? updated.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (created != null ? created.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }

    private VendorEntity vendor;

    @ManyToOne
    @javax.persistence.JoinColumn(name = "vendor_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    public VendorEntity getVendor() {
        return vendor;
    }

    public void setVendor(VendorEntity vendor) {
        this.vendor = vendor;
    }

    private ShippingDestinationEntity shippingDestination;

    @ManyToOne
    @javax.persistence.JoinColumn(name = "shipping_destination_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    public ShippingDestinationEntity getShippingDestination() {
        return shippingDestination;
    }

    public void setShippingDestination(ShippingDestinationEntity shippingDestination) {
        this.shippingDestination = shippingDestination;
    }

    private Collection<OrderCustomFieldEntity> orderCustomFields;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "order")
    public Collection<OrderCustomFieldEntity> getOrderCustomFields() {
        return orderCustomFields;
    }

    public void setOrderCustomFields(Collection<OrderCustomFieldEntity> orderCustomFields) {
        this.orderCustomFields = orderCustomFields;
    }

    private Collection<ProductEntity> products;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "order")
    public Collection<ProductEntity> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }

    public void setProducts(Collection<ProductEntity> products) {
        this.products = products;
    }
}
```

The stack trace:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property u found for type com.models.entities.OrderEntity
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:75)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:327)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:353)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:307)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:271)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:245)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:72)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:180)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.buildTree(PartTree.java:260)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:240)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:71)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:57)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:90)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:162)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:68)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:279)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:147)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getObject(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:153)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getObject(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:43)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:142)
    ... 26 more
```

**Update:** I just deleted and regenerated the entities from the database and still receive the same error.

Comment: I remember this question from like a few days back. It's too bad you haven't found an answer. I'd recommend changing the name of your fields in your `OrderEntity` class, as well as the queries, and seeing what errors you might get afterwards. You might see exactly what field it's talking about. Or if the error isn't from there, you'll know to look elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out, the issue was caused by conflicts with my Repository layer.  Despite me having a `Order.findByUUID` named query and my `OrderRepository` looking like:

```
@Repository
public interface OrderRepository extends JpaRepository<OrderEntity, Integer> {
    OrderEntity findByUUID(@Param("uuid") String uuid);

    List<OrderEntity> findByInProduction(@Param("inProduction") Boolean inProduction);
}
```

Removing the named query and change the above method to `findByUuid` was the solution.  I'm still unsure why it was failing, but this allowed me to get rid of the issue and begin debugging the application.

Comment: your `@Param("uuid")` and `@Param("inProduction")` is so unnecessary!

Answer (score 1):

The stacktrace shows you have a JPQL query (`repository.query.parser` lines) which includes something like `.u` on some object of type `OrderEntity`.
Maybe a text search for `.u` or `.u<space>` will help you spot the problem?

It doesn't have to be in the `OrderEntity` class itself.

Comment: I suspect that the JPA Repository engine assumes that capital letters are the start of a new word in the method name. UUID would therefore become four words (U, U, I & D) instead of one word.